# Should I create a separate project to do Unit Test? I'm using JUnit

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm new to software testing. I want to use JUnit to do the unit test on a Java project. The project is open source and it's a small application. So my question is - should I create a separate project to do testing or write the test code within the project? I use Netbeans btw. Also, can I generate test cases from existing class? On Netbeans, when you click File->New File->Unit Tests(Choose File Type)->Test for existing class, you are probably supposed to generate a test file but it turns out that you will just create new empty file... at least on my laptop... I'm not sure if that's the problem of the IDE..

Anyway, any answers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [Maven's default project structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

```
<projectDir>
    <src>
        <main>
            <java>
                <packages>
        <test>
            <java>
                <packages>
```

In this structure your tests are in the same project as your code but to not get compiled into your jar. Generally you put a unit test in the same package (under src/test/java) as the class under test. This gives organization and allows the unit test to access package-private (default scope) methods.